# Is it possible to change the type of an AngularJS variable in run time?

Tags: javascript, php, .net, angularjs

Is it possible to change the type of an AngularJS variable in run time?

```
$scope.addedDate = $scope.model.AddedDate;
$scope.addedDate = new Date();
```

$scope.addedDate is created by assigning @scope.model.AddedDate and its a string field and I want to convert @scope.AddedDate into a date field.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'date field'?

Comment: you want to convert $scope.model.AddedDate in to a Date object?

Comment: you can do anything which javascript allows you.

Comment: Right now the variable is a type of string.. I want to convert it into a Date Object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Javascript engine is a interpreter which will assign the type to the
>   variable based on the latest value it holds. Angularjs also Javascript
>   :)